# Triggers don't work well when I test my GAS project as Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, add-on

I'm developing google-sheets add-on.

I want to create functions that create triggers associated to individual spreadsheets.
I think that GAS SpreadSheetTriggerBuilder realize this function, but it doesn't work well.

When I test it as addon, triggers that I set using SpreadSheetTriggerBuilder don't work.
Whent it is GAS project, they work well.

Who knows my problem??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written  in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons#testing_details),

> Installable triggers aren't supported when testing. Functionality that depends on installable triggers are not testable.

Therefore you can't test those triggers.